# Infinite KeyPress/-Release Events

Tags: 14.04

so, here's my problem:
since I upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04, I noticed that some things don't work as they should. for example I can't assing any keybindings and while writing, my screen freezes every few seconds like when my computer is out of ressources. 
After some testing, I came as far as to notice that I get permanently looping KeyPress and KeyRelease Events causing disruptions in some other programs.

This is the the part of the output I get when running  `xev` which keeps repeating itself at least 50 times per second:

```
KeyPress event, serial 45, synthetic NO, window 0x4600001,
    root 0x2d6, subw 0x0, time 27516728, (619,347), root:(2546,429),
    state 0x10, keycode 248 (keysym 0x0, NoSymbol), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 45, synthetic NO, window 0x4600001,
    root 0x2d6, subw 0x0, time 27516728, (619,347), root:(2546,429),
    state 0x10, keycode 248 (keysym 0x0, NoSymbol), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

I tried disconnecting Hardware parts which could cause this, without success.
What I did then was testing different Ubuntu Versions/Distros:

Ubuntu 12.10 doesn't have the Problem.
Elementary OS Luna (based on Ubuntu 12.04) also doesn't have this problem.
Elementary OS Freya (based on Ubuntu 14.04) has it again.

Currently I am on Ubuntu 14.04 again trying to pinpoint the cause since weeks by myself, without any success.
So, all I know is that the problem is caused by something that is implemented since Ubuntu 14.04 and as far as I've read things, it's likely something in the kernel.

My question is now: Does anyone know how I could find the cause for this and fix it, OR if said isn't possible, maybe just how I could completely block the KeyPress/-Release Events so they don't interfere anymore?